# Proof that splitting field of polynomial ring is algebraically closed

Tags: proof-verification, galois-theory, splitting-field

Let $F$ be a field and let $K$ be the splitting field of $F[x]$. Then $K$ is algebraically closed. This is a theorem we proved yesterday in my algebra class. The strategy was to take a polynomial $f(x) \in K[x]$ and look at the intermediate field produced by adjoining the coefficients of $f(x)$ to $F$. I am confused as to how this is necessary however. What is wrong with the following proof?

Let $f(x) \in L[x]$. Now $f(x)$ has a splitting field $L/K$, so there exists some $\alpha \in L$ such that $f(\alpha) = 0$. Since $L/K$ and $K/F$ are both splitting fields, they are both algebraic extensions, hence $L/F$ is algebraic. Therefore $\alpha$ has a minimal polynomial $m_{\alpha}(x) \in F[x]$. Since $K$ is the splitting field of $F[x]$, $m_{\alpha}(x)$ splits over $K$, hence $\alpha \in K$. Therefore $f(x)$ has a root in $K$, so $K$ is algebraically closed. Thanks!

Comment: To prove a field is algebraically closed, you must prove EVERY polynomial splits, not just the particular given $f$ splits.

Comment: Is the splitting field of the polynomial ring not the field in which every polynomial splits into linear factors ? In this case, the claim would be trivial.

Comment: @Peter: no, the claim is not trivial. By definition, every $f \in F[x]$ splits over $K$. You now need to show that every $f \in K[x]$ splits over $K$.

Comment: OK, I assumed the wrong definition of "splitting field of a polynomial ring".

Comment: @Ethan: you seem to be using $L$ to mean two things, both an extension containing all the coefficients of an arbitrary $f(x) \in K[x]$ and the splitting field of $f$. In general the latter will be bigger than the former.

Comment: @walkar: I don't understand this criticism. There is no particular given $f$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I made a typo, edited it. I meant $L$ in the latter sense; the splitting field of $f(x) \in K[x]$.